# Four Fun-derful Rebuses

Tags: rebus

<sup><sup>This is an entry to the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #26](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/fortnightly-topic-challenge-26-rebus): [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus).</sup></sup>

---

I've created a new kind of rebus for you!
Let's try one together. An easy one, too:

[image: GUN]

How simple, how simple! But come on, you're smarter
than that. How 'bout one a little bit harder:

[image: X]

Now that's more like it! A bit of a puzzle.
Now here's a third that is sure to confuzzle:

[image: CKCKCKCK]

Well, now that you've solved that, you think you're the best?
Then come take a crack at the ultimate test:

[image: SUC ISA]

The mods asked for rebuses, and I answered the call
With pictures, and puzzles, and poems *et al.*

Comment: Do colors matter or the content is enough?

Comment: @Techidiot the colors are intentional.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rebuses work by

> making use of the hexcodes for each colour.

Rebus 1 is

> GUN in #beebee, giving BB GUN.

Rebus 2 is

> X in #ceeded, giving EXCEEDED.

Rebus 3 is

> CK in #feedba arranged in a cycle, giving FEEDBACK LOOP.

Rebus 4 is

> SUC in #ceeded then ISA in #be11a1 giving SUCCEEDED ISABELLA I. The successor of Isabella I of Castille appears to be JOANNA (of Castille).

As a side note, amusingly @Walt in chat thought that the first rebus looked like GUN in powder blue, which would have given GUNPOWDER had it been correct.

Comment: How the heck is #1 the easiest? What's a BB gun anyway?

Comment: Still a bit unconvinced by my answer for #4, but we'll see when OP confirms/denies.

Comment: @randal'thor a gun that shoots little pellets instead of bullets iirc

Comment: This is all correct - my intended answer for #4 was "Succeeded BY", but there's no real way to interpret one over the other and I knew it was a coin flip when posting it!

Comment: @randal'thor my mistake - BB guns are something very common where I'm from. It didn't even cross my mind that it could be a localized product!